# How can I setup multiple users to connect to an ubuntu server?

Tags: server, windows, samba

I have recently been setting up a samba file server. I have managed to connect my windows pc to the main account (I went map network drive then \servername\user) However, there are other people who need to connect to the server on another account (\servername\user2) whenever I try to connect to the other account I get an error from windows about not being able to access \Servername\user2 is there something else I need to setup so that they both connect at once?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured `/etc/samba/smb.conf` for shared folders then you must assign group or user to this share.

e.g if you have share:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /srv/samba/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

Then you can give access to this share to other users multiple ways. You can give access to this folder only for one user e.g:

`sudo chown john:john /srv/samba/share/`

But you can also give access to this folder to certain group that contains people you need to give access to this folder.

`sudo chgrp users /srv/samba/share/`

or

`sudo chown -R john:users /srv/samba/share/`

Comment: You welcome, you can simply mark this answer as correct (the green check image).